# Display Excel's file in jsp

Tags: excel, jsp, browser

i'm working on manipulation of Excel's file and i wanted to know if it was possible to display and alter excel's data directly from jsp? maybe there are some visual framework who allows this kind of manipualtion. Apache Poi dosnt allow that. for detail i'm using SPRING MVC for my application's development.
[EDIT]: in another terms. how can i display excel's file on browser using java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that i get is to use an extension on my browser that help to open excel's using a browser. it's not what i really want but it helps somehow